# How to get the position information of a value of an array inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to get the information of a position of an array inside the loop.

I've **two** variables.

```
var columns = 4, 
    rows = 5;
```

So, the array would be look like this according to the value of i (in loop):

[image]

Now, I've to produce an array of information.

```
var positions = [], 
    totalCount = columns * rows;

for (var i = 1; i <= totalCount; i++) {
    var informationObject = {
        "column": "column number",
        "row": "row number",
        "column_count": "column count",
        "row_count": "row count",
    };

    positions.push(informationObject);
}

console.log(positions);
```

Detailed architecture of this is here:

[image]

I wan't to prepare this **positions** array differently according to the position information.

> You may ask me what I've tried. I actually doing it custom code. Like `if(i=7){//do operation}`, I mean totally humanize code. This is getting very weird. I think there has a way to do this dynamically.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For indexing, that starts at 0, `i % 4` is, in order: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... . Similarly, `Math.floor(i / 4)` is 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, ... . Maybe that helps.

Comment: Additionally the column count and row count can be determined mathematically instead of hard-coding the output for each value of `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard-coding the output based on `i` is not a viable solution. The property values you are looking to output can be obtained through the use of the Modulo operator (`%`) and division:

```js
var columns = 4,
  rows = 5,
  positions = [],
  totalCount = columns * rows;

for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
  let r = Math.ceil(i / columns);
  let c = (i % columns) + 1;
  
  positions.push({
    column: c,
    row: r,
    column_count: r,
    row_count: c
  });
}

console.log(positions);
```

For further information see the following MDN links:

- [Modulo operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)
- [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Comment: O man, you're genius. This is actually what I need. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

using two for loops is what you want to do to easily capture x/y information. where x represents left/right and y up/down.

is this what you are looking for then?

```
var columns = 4, 
    rows = 5;
var positions = [], 

for (let x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
    for(let y=1;y<=rows;y++){
    var informationObject = {
            "column": x,
            "row": y,
            "column_count": y,
            "row_count": x,
        };

        positions.push(informationObject);
    }
}

console.log(positions);
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted a bit different thing. @Rory McCrossan's answer worked for me.